# Material Design 3 "colorSurface" is influenced by "colorPrimary"

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to change the background color of a dialog and of a bottom sheet by setting the `colorSurface` attribute (as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md)), but the color I see when I run the app is different than the color I set in the code.

Let's say I want to have a dialog with a **white background**, so I write the following code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#DD0000</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

or:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#DD0000</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.AlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="colorSurface">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

and I display the dialog using this code:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMessage("Message")
    .setNegativeButton("Positive") { _, _ -> }
    .setPositiveButton("Negative") { _, _ -> }
    .show()
```

The result is a dialog with a **pink background** color and this seems to happen because `colorPrimary` is red. In the same way, if I set `#000000` as `colorSurface`, I don't get a pure black background. The same thing happens when I try to set the background of a bottom sheet.

Why does this happen?
Is this behaviour documented and can it be disabled?

Thanks!

[image: Dialog with pink background]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the "elevation overlay" and it can be disabled using:

```
<item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
```

[image]

See https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1133 for more details.